# What difference does it make when we pluralize certain nouns instead of others?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

For example:

> 1. We need to be able to tell the differences between each **kind** of **problem**.
> 2. We need to be able to tell the differences between each **kinds** of **problem**.
> 3. We need to be able to tell the differences between each **kind** of **problems**.
> 4. We need to be able to tell the differences between each **kinds** of **problems**.

What rule in English are we dealing with here? (2) and (3) sounds off, but I can't explain the grammatical reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

**[difference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/difference)** can be countable or uncountable. When we use it in the set phrase **tell the difference**, we almost always treat it as uncountable, so we use **difference** in the singular, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tell%20the%20difference%2Ctell%20the%20differences&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctell%20the%20difference%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctell%20the%20differences%3B%2Cc0) shows. Here is the correct sentence:

> We need to be able to tell the difference between ...

If you want to make it clear that there are multiple differences between any two kinds of problem, it would be better to use **spot** or **identify**, because these are not associated with the uncountable form of **difference**.

> We need to be able to spot the differences between ...

When you use **between**, you have to follow it by at least two things:

> What is the difference between a cat? - *incorrect*
> What is the difference between a cat and a dog? - *correct*

**each** always describes just one item out of many, so the noun that follows it must be singular. Remember, though, that **between** has to be followed by at least two things, so you can't use **each kind** after **between**.

If, instead, you use **different** or **the various**, that means that you are talking about at least two things, so you use plural, and it works after **between**:

> We need to be able to tell the difference between different kinds of problem

When you use the word **of**, you generally follow it by a singular.

> ... different kinds of problem